# "===" true or false?

Tags: logic

I understand or rather, I have heard, that Gödel as part of his incompleteness theorem enumerates all statements. But how do you single out those that can be used in a test of provability. You will encounter such statements as “===” etc?

Are these considered true (since they obviously don’t contradict anything) or how is that done?

Comment: "===" is not a statement at all. Part of Gödel's work defines a function for deciding whether a given string of symbols is a syntactically correct (known as "well-formed" in the logic jargon) formula.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the series of symbols $===$ has a number in Gödel's system.  His paper has a series of functions and predicates, each building on the earlier ones.  He builds up from defining a predicate Prime(n), which is true if $n$ is prime, later Term(n), which is true if $n$ represents a term (a variable or constant), and eventually to wff(n), which is true if $n$ represents a well formed formula.  Even later comes axiom(n), which is true if $n$ represents one of the axioms of PA and so on.  If $m$ represents ===, wff(m)  will be false.

Comment: So the theorem is restricted to well formed formulas with no internal wff identification process.

Comment: It has an internal wff identification.  The point of the theorem is to construct an undecidable wff.  Only wffs can have truth values.